# got stuck with python code. can someone help to solve the highlighted errors. thanks a lot

Tags: shadow

while writing the code i faced the following errors

this is about matching different databases.
somee errors of variables came out.`your text`

Enclosed the code and errors:
`[ part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36FVs.png)`
`[ part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHL4w.png)`
`[ part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgf8s.png)`
`[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9BAF.png)`

I hope some guys can support this issue, as I got stuck during the coding process.

Comment: Post the code itself, not pictures of code, please